# Dependency Injection that causes circular dependency and stack overflow, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm new to the Dependency injection world and just started working on a project that uses Unity 2.0.  Everything was working great until I created a MVC service that references another service that in turn references the other service.  As a result I get a stack overflow exception. I understand what is happening and it makes sense but it made me stop and think that I might be doing something wrong.  Is there a best practice for ensuring this doesn't happen?

```
public AccountService(IUserRepository userRepository, IAuthenticationService authService...

public AuthenticationService(IUserRepository userRepository, IAccountService accountService...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it made me stop and think that I might be doing something wrong

Yes, your design is wrong. You should avoid circular references in your objects.

> Is there a best practice for ensuring this doesn't happen?

Just break this circular reference in your objects hierarchy. Rethink your design.

Comment: thanks, so do you think I should avoid services referencing services or allow it just make sure to avoid circular references?

Comment: @NullReference, avoid circular references, that's for sure. As far as services referencing services is concerned, it will depend on what exactly are you designing and how you are designing it. Probably a bad idea but I don't want to pronounce myself without having any context about your scenario.